# Self-built reeds for Blues Harp

Tags: instruments, repair, harmonica

A reed of my C blues harp went broken and I don't have the opportunity to replace the harp or the reed board until I need it.

As a improvised solution, I thought of cutting a reed-shaped piece out of a brass foil (because I think reed are made of brass) and placing it in the harp somehow.

Are there any better solutions or advices for this?

Answer (score 2):

Typically they are brass but other metals such as aluminum and steel have been used.  That's great if you can reverse engineer it with a good pair of calipers.  Inside the instrument they are attached to the reed plate with screws. Make sure to use a similar material to the surrounding reeds, tune the reed, and gap it to the slot properly. Here's a site with good pictures of the internals: https://fredrikhertzberg.com/category/maintenance/